# Checking multiple fences with one fence status check

Tags: vulkan

Checking fence status to see if a queue submission has completed should be avoided as such as possible. I think it's a common thing to do that every frame fences for queue submissions are checked and then command buffers are released, and any resources too (either to be destroyed or recycled). Let's just say that you want to check if all submissions submitted on a certain frame have been completed, let's say n, or n + 1 frames ago. You could check all the fences for multiple submissions in one go. Except that you can't, vkGetFenceStatus only takes one fence as an argument ( or is there a way to check multiple fences?)

Is the idea of making a dummy submission that has a wait semaphore waiting for multiple previous submissions, and then checking the fence status on that one dummy submission a good idea?

Comment: "*Let's just say that you want to check if all submissions submitted on a certain frame have been completed*" Ideally, that should be exactly one submission per-queue. Is there a reason to make more than one submission per-queue, per-frame?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the checking of status that is expensive, it's blocking and waiting for completion so you stall the CPU and drain the pipeline.

You solve this by pipelining your queues deeply enough that you only ever "wait" on semaphores/fences that are already complete. This typically requires N-buffering resources so you have enough resources to avoid the need to wait "too soon". If you do this properly, I'd expect the CPU cost of testing the fences here to be negligible.

Comment: When I did testing it showed that the actual checking of the fence status was slow. When I say slow I mean 'slow' in terms of running 16 or 8 ms main loop, and so it's definitely something I want to avoid. Nicol Bolas said pretty much the same thing as you, ie., to check fence status only when you're fairly certain the submission has completed, so this might be done for submissions submitted n + whatever frames ago. However the thing is that checking each frame may have many submissions, meaning checking multiple fences (and yes, vkGetFenceStatus( ) itself is quite slow.

Comment: That's why I had the idea of using a dummy submission that doesn't commence until all the submissions of a particular frame have finished, then you only check one fence (for that one). I'm not experienced with this so I don't know if this is a good idea / thing that is done.

Comment: I think the `VkQueueSubmit` complete semaphores gives you this behavior anyway, and given queues submits are "in order" (handwave), you probably get the behaviour you need on the CPU side.

Comment: @Zebrafish: "*the thing is that checking each frame may have many submissions*" No, it should not. The Vulkan standard goes out of its way to warn you *not* to call `vkQueueSubmit` any more than you absolutely have to.